# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not open file "" for writing: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, airflow

Запускаю AirFlow DAG чтобы скопировать данные из таблицы в файл. AirFlow запускается в  Docker.

Данные пробую скопировать так:

```
sql = f"COPY {table_name} TO '{full_file_path}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not open file "/opt/***/upload-data/aisles.csv" for writing: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

Директория примаунчена через docker-compose:

```
- ./upload-data:/opt/airflow/upload-data
```

Сам файл создал: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Oct 21 16:23 aisles.csv*`

Comment: в команде `copy to file` указываются пути на сервере postgres, а не на хосте где выполняется клиент.

Comment: ааа, я понял. спасибо! а как сделать, чтобы сохранило на сервере клиента?

Comment: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало.